# Still not understanding a detail in a posted proof of an algebraic inequality

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, proof-explanation

While working through a proof I am struggling with one section in it where the following estimate is established:

> For real numbers $\,a,b,c\,$ which satisfy $\,0<a,b\,$ and $\,0\leqslant c\leqslant a,b\,$ one has
> $$\frac ab + \frac ba \;\leqslant\; \frac{a^2+bc}{b^2+c^2} + \frac{b^2+ac}{a^2+c^2}\tag{1}\,.$$

The line of argumentation starts from $\,ac+bc\leqslant a^2+b^2\,$
which is clear from the givens. $\checkmark$
Then
$$ab(a-b)+c(bc-a^2)\leqslant ab(a-b)+c(b^2-ac)\tag{2}$$
follows. $\checkmark$
Despite the WLOG-assumption $b\leqslant a$, I cannot grasp the subsequent implication
$$\frac{ab(a-b) +bc^2-a^2c}{a(a^2+c^2)}\;\leqslant\;\frac{ab(a-b)+b^2c-ac^2}{b(b^2+c^2)}\,,\tag{007}$$

which goes along the guideline "Increase the numerator & Decrease the denominator", because
*both numerators in $(007)$ alias $(2)$ may be negative!*
I hope you see my difficulty in understanding this one.

> Thus may I ask if $(1)$ is correct & how it can be proven eventually?

The said proof belongs to an inequality [on AoPS](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6t243f6h260824_abcgt0), and the solution which I'd like to understand was posted on 24/04/2016 by luofangxiang.
[A screen-shot of it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TLWOX.png) is also included, to avoid missunderstanding which one is meant.

---

*Edit to summarise:*
The RHS of $(2)$ cannot get negative. This rectifies my above-noted statement in italics.
From mathlove's answer one deduces
$$ab(a-b) +b^2c -ac^2 \:=\: (a-b)(b-c)(a-c) + c(a-c)^2 + c^2(b-c)\:\geqslant\: 0\,.$$
Thus overall, the estimate $(1)$ is a correct one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $0\leqslant c\leqslant b\leqslant a$, then RHS of $(2)$ is non-negative.

Letting $b=c+p$ and $a=c+p+q$ where $p,q\geqslant 0$, we get
$$\text{RHS of $(2)$}=c^2 p + c p^2 + 2 c p q + c q^2 + p^2 q + p q^2\geqslant 0$$

So, $(007)$ is correct.